# How do you conditionally call a target based on a target variable (Makefile)?

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, target

I want a different version of the clean target to run based on whether `make dev` or `make prod` are run on a makefile.

I'm not compiling anything per se, just want to conditionally call a particular target or set of targets based on a variable, for example:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_ENV),"development")
clean: -clean
else
clean: -clean-info
endif

#---------------------------------
dev: BUILD_ENV = development
dev: dev-setup which-env

#---------------------------------
prod: BUILD_ENV = production
prod: prod-setup which-env

#---------------------------------


which-env: clean
    @echo -e "$(GREEN)$(BUILD_ENV)!$(CLEAR)"

-clean: -clean-info -clean-logs | silent
    @echo -e "$(GREEN)</CLEAN>$(CLEAR)"

-clean-info:
    @echo -e "$(GREEN)<CLEAN>...$(CLEAR)"

-clean-logs:
    @echo -e " $(GREY)Removing log and status files $(CLEAR)";
    @if [ -d .stat ]; then rm -rf .stat; fi
    @rm -f *.log || true
```

Is there a way to do this with Makefiles? I havent found anything yet that illustrates this use-case.

I'm not trying to specifically clean anything or build anything this is just an example of me trying to conditionally call a set of targets. The actual targets could be anything else.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  You want to run the appropriate `clean` target when you run `make dev` or `make prod`?  But wouldn't that just clean up the things you just got through creating?  Or, are you trying to say that when you run `make clean` you want to run the version of the target based on whichever you ran last, either `make dev` or `make prod`?

Comment: @MadScientist -- this is just an example -- dont get to caught up in the particular clean commands, I only wrote this to demonstrate what Im trying to do with targets. In this case I only want to run the clean target if the BUILD_ENV variable is set to development, or just clean_info otherwise. ( I just want a way to call a specific set of targets based on the value of a variable. )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not at all clear that what you're asking for is really what you want, but here goes:

```
all:

ifeq ($(BUILD_ENV),development)
all: clean-dev
else
all: clean-other
endif

clean-dev:
    @echo running $@, doing something

clean-other:
    @echo running $@, doing something else
```

If you run `make BUILD_ENV=development`, you'll get something; if you run `make` or `make BUILD_ENV=production` you'll get something else.

Comment: maybe the code is misleading -- all i want is to run a dang conditional target! I tried doing what you have listed above but it did not work. Maybe its the version of make I'm running (osx/homebrew)

Comment: @qodeninja: [facepalm] The above works with GNUMake 3.81, but yes, if you're running a home-made Make tool, you might get strange results. It sounds as if the only person who can answer questions about your version of make is you.

Comment: Thanks! GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Comment: Strange language construct, `all:` is redefining `all:`?  Why the first `all`?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: The first `all` is not necessary in this case, but it makes the *first target* much easier to find by eye.

Comment: Owner accepted answer, yet we still do not know how to conditionally test the target.